# Turn on Ime-mode japanese in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, ime

Is there a way to turn on IME-mode japanese when input in chrome .
I know style

```
style="ime-mode:active"
```

is not supported for chrome browser.
Anyone have any other way for chrome ?

when the customer is Japanese, enter the input tag on chrome browser. then ime-mode in os will change the status to Japanese typing

Comment: I'm curious why you believe it's important to automatically turn on the Japanese IME for Japanese customers? If Japanese customers actually want to type in Japanese, they already know how to quickly turn on the Japanese IME themselves (by pressing one key or some key combination). I doubt your Japanese customers see it as a problem that you don't turn on the Japanese IME automatically for them. In fact, it's more likely most Japanese customers would prefer that you don't do that, and would be surprised by the unexpected behavior if you did. But maybe you have evidence that suggests otherwise?

Comment: It was a request from the Japanese. They want when entering data into the form, with Input fields, when to focus on it. computer's percussion, they will automatically switch to Japanese without having to use keystrokes. i tried with style="ime-mode:active" but it only works with firefox but chrome doesn't support it. I think there will be another way

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it takes time.

Write a Python program that turns on the IME and a Chrome extension that calls it using native messaging.
And inject the Chrome extension into your Html.

Html

```html
  <input id="text" type="text">
```

JavaScript

```js
  document.getElementById("text").onfocus = () => {
    // Write the code that calls the Python program here.
  }
```

Python

```py
import pywinauto

# The IME hotkey in this example is Ctrl+Space.
pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('^{SPACE}')
```